# Android Studio app crashes on first launch

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm building my first ever Android Studio application. I tested it in the emulator and there are no problems whatsoever. After I generate the signed APK and install it on my phone, the first time I open the app it crashes instantly. When I try to run it again, there's no problems. Is there any way to find the root cause of this?

Comment: Run it on your device from Android Studio. This way you will have logs of the Error.

Comment: Debug your code, see logcat that's the only way to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Change Build Variant to release (you can find it in bottom left corner)
2. Configure `signingConfigs` in `File > Project Structure... > (Modules) app > Signing`
3. Run app using release variant on emulator or real device and observe Logcat